# Kotlin - Problem extending a generic class and returning a subtype

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, hierarchy

I have the following situation:

- An abstract generic class

```kotlin
abstract class K<T> {
  abstract fun bind(itemModel: T)
}
```

- A class that extends from `K`

```kotlin
class A : K<ModelA> {
    override fun bind(itemModel: ModelA) {
        // ... do anything
    }
}

class B : K<ModelB> {
    override fun bind(itemModel: ModelB) {
        // ... do anything
    }
}
```

- Another class, this is a factory that returns a subtype of K based on some parameter:

```kotlin
class Factory {
    companion object {
        const val TYPE_A: Int = 0
        const val TYPE_B: Int = 1

        fun create(type: Int): K {
            return when (type) {
                TYPE_A -> A()
                TYPE_B -> B()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, I'm getting an error in return type section of `Factory.create` method, it says: "One type argument expected for class K< T >". It's clear that I'm trying to return a subtype of K in `create` method, and it's the only thing that matters, not the specific type of a generic.

This is possible in **Java**. What is the correct way in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things to improve here (updated according to the comment).

- You need to add default value if the parameter in not `TYPE_A` or `TYPE_B`
- Add * to parametrized K return type.

As a result it will be something like that:

```
fun create(type: Int): K<*> {
   return when (type) {
       TYPE_A -> A()
       TYPE_B -> B()
       else -> throw IllegalStateException("useful message")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `K` isn't a complete type just like you can't return a `List` in Java - you have to return a `List<Something>`. So you need to say that this will return a `K<Any>` (or some other type bound).

However, now you also have a type variance issue as a `K<A>` is not a subtype of `K<Any>` unless the declaration of `K` is `K<out T>` but your `bind` method has `T` in the `in` position so that's not possible. That makes sense because if I give you a the result of calling `create` you haven no way to know what types of things you can pass to `bind` so it's not that useful.

As noted in the previous reply you can have create return `K<*>` and that will compile but I'm not sure how useful that would be since you'll have to know the actual type in order to call `bind` - that is you'll have to cast whatever `create` returns in which case you can probably just construct the type-specific thing to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it compile by returning `K<*>`, but you won't be able to do much with the returned instance. In Java, you can do this with raw types by ignoring the compiler warnings and simply risk the ClassCastExceptions when you start trying to call methods on the returned object, but then why use generics at all?

Instead, you can use a reified type so the caller can pass the type the generated instance can handle instead of some number:

```
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    inline fun <reified T> create(): K<T> {
        return when (T::class) {
            ModelA::class -> A()
            ModelB::class -> B()
            else -> error("unsupported type")
        } as K<T>
    }
```